# Spring Boot MQ listener enable always

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have `Spring boot` application which reads the message from IBM QUEUE. I want my Listener queue to keep listening for new message in Queue but I see it reads the message once then stop listening. below is the code is that anything I am missing here?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        System.out.println("******done!!!");
    }


    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println("jmsTemplate:  " + jmsTemplate);
            final Message message =  jmsTemplate.receive("MYQUEUE");
            String msgBody = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
            System.out.println("message RECEIVED :    " + message);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

        
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to consume multiple messages, you'd need to call jmsTemplate.receive() multiple times. Perhaps in a loop?

But I'd recommend making use of [@JmsListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/annotation/JmsListener.html) so that you don't even have to worry about writing your own polling mechanism.

[Here is a tutorial on @JmsListener](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/). You really just need to supply a `JmsListenerContainerFactory` bean, and annotate a method with `@JmsListener`, and that method will be invoked every time the queue you subscribe to receives a message.

```java
  @Bean
  public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                          DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
    return factory;
  }
```

```java
  @JmsListener(destination = "mailbox", containerFactory = "myFactory")
  public void receiveMessage(Email email) {
    System.out.println("Received <" + email + ">");
  }
```

Comment: Since the OP is using Spring Boot; it (Boot) will automatically configure a container factory with the default name `jmsListenerContainerFactory`.

Comment: `SimpleJmsListenerContainerFactory` is actually better than Default with IBM MQ, it uses call backs instead of polling the queue.